# How can I test a higher-order function using QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a higher-order function that I want to test, and one of the properties I want to test is what it does with the functions that are passed in.  For purposes of illustration, here is a contrived example:

```
gen :: a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> Bool) -> a
```

The idea is roughly that this is an example generator.  I'm going to start with a single `a`, create a singleton  list of `[a]`, then make new lists of `[a]` until a predicate tells me to stop.  A call might look like this:

```
gen init next stop
```

where

```
init :: a
next :: [a] -> [a]
stop :: [a] -> Bool
```

Here's the property I'd like to test:

> On any call to `gen init next stop`, `gen` promises never to pass an empty list to `next`.

**Can I test this property using QuickCheck**, and if so, how?

Comment: Here's a related property: "For any non-empty input, `next` will produce a non-empty output".  You might be interested in testing this instead, or in addition to, the property you mention.

Comment: @JohnL Indeed so!  But that's a property of `next`, not `gen`, and `next` is first-order, so I know how to test it.

Answer (score 10):

While it would help if you gave the implementation of `gen`, I am
guessing that it goes something like this:

```
gen :: a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> Bool) -> a
gen init next stop = loop [init]
  where
    loop xs | stop xs   = head xs
            | otherwise = loop (next xs)
```

The property you want to test is that `next` is never supplied an
empty list. An obstacle to test this is that you want to check an
internal loop invariant inside `gen`, so this needs to be available from
the outside. Let us modify `gen` to return this information:

```
genWitness :: a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> Bool) -> (a,[[a]])
genWitness init next stop = loop [init]
  where
    loop xs | stop xs   = (head xs,[xs])
            | otherwise = second (xs:) (loop (next xs))
```

We use `second` from
[Control.Arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v%3asecond).
The original `gen` is easily defined in terms of `genWitness:`

```
gen' :: a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> Bool) -> a
gen' init next stop = fst (genWitness init next stop)
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation this will not give us much overhead. Back to
the property! To enable showing generated functions from QuickCheck,
we use the module
[Test.QuickCheck.Function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html).
While it is not strictly necessary here, a good habit is to
monomorphise the property: we use lists of `Int`s instead of allowing
the monomorphism restriction making them to unit lists. Let us now state
the property:

```
prop_gen :: Int -> (Fun [Int] [Int]) -> (Fun [Int] Bool) -> Bool
prop_gen init (Fun _ next) (Fun _ stop) =
    let trace = snd (genWitness init next stop)
    in  all (not . null) trace
```

Let us try the running it with QuickCheck:

```
ghci> quickCheck prop_gen
```

Something seems to loop... Yes of course: `gen` loops if `stop` on the
lists from `next` is never `True`! Let us instead try to look at finite prefixes of the input trace
instead:

```
prop_gen_prefix :: Int -> (Fun [Int] [Int]) -> (Fun [Int] Bool) -> Int -> Bool
prop_gen_prefix init (Fun _ next) (Fun _ stop) prefix_length =
    let trace = snd (genWitness init next stop)
    in  all (not . null) (take prefix_length trace)
```

We now quickly get a a counter-example:

```
385
{_->[]}
{_->False}
2
```

The second function is the argument `next`, and if it returns the empty list,
then the loop in `gen` will give `next` an empty list.

I hope this answers this question and that it gives you some insight
in how to test higher-order functions with QuickCheck.

Comment: if you altered `gen` to `gen :: Monad m => a -> ([a] -> m [a]) -> ([a] -> m Bool) -> m a`, then you could put your witnessing code inside `next` (and `stop`), and not worry about sullying the implementation with such logging.

Comment: Wow.  I was expecting to put some kind of wrapper around `gen`, but I'm not sure I want to have to muck up my nice clean `gen` with this extra gunk.  I will look into it an get back to you.

Comment: @NormanRamsey: using @rampion's suggestion by just doing it monadic and then use the writer monad to do a trace wouldn't require too much gunk. Then `next` only needs to write its input to the writer monad.

Comment: @NormanRamsey I believe the difficulty in testing is that the gen function is not so clean after all.  Have you considered making the first argument a list instead of a single element?  This would allow testing of this property MUCH easier, since you could just pass an empty list to test this condition instead of relying on the behavior of the next and stop functions in your test.

Comment: @nightski : How would that help? That would immediate violate the property. The property you really want to show is that the inner "loop", of which I have merely given an example implementation above, that `next` never gets an empty list, and these lists would come from `next` itself and possible combinations and rearrangements from inside the loop: that's what we must test.

Answer (score 4):

It is possibly in bad taste to abuse this, but QuickCheck *does* fail a function if it throws an exception. So, to test, just give it a function that throws an exception for the empty case. Adapting danr's answer:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function
import Control.DeepSeq

prop_gen :: Int -> (Fun [Int] [Int]) -> (Fun [Int] Bool) -> Bool
prop_gen x (Fun _ next) (Fun _ stop) = gen x next' stop `deepseq` True
  where next' [] = undefined
        next' xs = next xs
```

This technique does not require you to modify `gen`.

Comment: There's one problem with this: if the `stop` function never returns `True`, it'll loop forever.  Instead of a QuickCheck provided function, the user needs to create a `stop` that's guaranteed to return `True` at some point.  Short of a function like `const True`, this may be difficult to guarantee.